# I want to be able to use 4 different variables in a select statement in c ++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

First off I am new to C++ and I am trying to learn it to update one of my companies legacy apps. Which is on windows xp and visual c++ 6.0 which is not fun.. any ways I have this select statement that reads my database and searches for a ResourceID like what ever I set my m_operSet. I want to be able to use 4 specific variables in this like statement. problem is when I set it to a specific one it will not find any other resources besides what I set it to. here is my code this is my operations.Set.cpp and my bordDlg.cpp.

This is my list of variables I wish to use for the m_operSet

'COB'

'NIC'

'SIC'

'PRS'

Basically I want to use a if else statement.. say if COB use COB ifelse NIC use NIC ifelse SIC use SIC IFelse PRS use PRS

## BordDlg.cpp

```
 // BordDlg.cpp : implementation file

        #include "operationSet.h"
        #include "custSet.h"


        // Initial filter is set in m_custSet Constuctor
        m_custSet.setBaseID(baseID);
        m_custSet.setLotID(lotID);

        // Initial filter is set in m_operSet Constuctor
        m_operSet.setBaseID(baseID);
        m_operSet.setLotID(lotID);
        m_operSet.setSubID(subID);
        m_operSet.setSplitID(splitID);

        // This is where I set this at and where I want to use either 'COB' 'NIC' 'SIC' 'PRS'
        m_operSet.setResourceID("COB");
```

## operationSet.cpp

```
        // operationSet.cpp : implementation file
        //

        #include "stdafx.h"

        #include "operationSet.h"


         void operationSet::setBaseID(CString baseID)
         {
            m_strFilter += "and WORKORDER_BASE_ID LIKE '" + baseID + " ";
         } 

         void operationSet::setLotID(CString lotID)
         {
            m_strFilter += "and WORKORDER_LOT_ID LIKE '" + lotID + "' ";
         } 

         void operationSet::setSplitID(CString splitID)
         {
            m_strFilter +=  "and [WORKORDER_SPLIT_ID] LIKE '" + splitID + "' ";

         }

         void operationSet::setSubID(CString subID)
         {
            m_strFilter +=  "and [WORKORDER_SUB_ID] LIKE '" + subID + "' ";

         }

         void operationSet::setResourceID(CString resID)
         {
                m_strFilter +=  "and [RESOURCE_ID] LIKE '" + resID + "' ";

         }
```

Comment: `This is where I set this at and where I want to use either 'COB' 'NIC' 'SIC' 'PRS'`  So what is your criteria for choosing?  You have a vague "if COB then use COB" in your question, but you should tell us what "if COB" is supposed to mean.  Is 'COB' in this case an integer, and you want to call the function using the string "COB"?

Comment: So if your select statement is not working, what is the value of `m_strFilter` you are actually using after setting all those IDs?

Comment: these variable's are tied into my operationsSet. This application is a order sheet for customers to use. these are all strings so they could virtually be anything I just want it find ones only with Resource id like 'COB' or like 'NIC' or like 'SIC' or like 'PRS'. if that makes sense

Comment: That's my question how can I set it to be all of them at the same time to filter for RESOURCE ID so I would like something like this maybe that kind of what I am not sure about is the proper syntax to say this if(m_operSet.ResourceID == "COB")  ;  ifelse(m_operSet ResourceID == "NIC")   and so on for the next 2 "SIC" "PRS"

Comment: I wasn't looking for an explanation of what your query means. If your query isn't working, show the *actual query string* that gets built so we can see what's wrong. The code that builds the query is relevant only after you know what's wrong with your query.

Comment: try `m_operSet.setResourceID("COB or NIC or SIC or PRS");` or `m_operSet.setResourceID("(COB or NIC or SIC or PRS)");`

Comment: The post is unclear. But as far as syntax goes: if{ } else if{ } else if{ } else{ }

Comment: @bolov that didn't work

Comment: try `m_operSet.setResourceID("COB' or 'NIC' or 'SIC' or 'PRS");`  Note the apostrophes around each word, except the ends of the string.

Comment: try `m_operSet.setResourceID("COB' or [RESOURCE_ID] LIKE 'NIC' or [RESOURCE_ID] LIKE 'SIC' or [RESOURCE_ID] LIKE 'PRS");`

Comment: I tried both revised comments and for the first one I got invalid relational operator and for the second it just froze my application and I had to force quit it. thank you for you help btw! @bolov

Comment: try with the last one and with this modified: `m_strFilter +=  "and ( [RESOURCE_ID] LIKE '" + resID + "' ) ";`

Comment: MAN YOU ARE AWESOME THAT WORKED THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU!!!!! @bolov if you want to make it into an answer I will gladly accept it for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those functions build a query string like this:

```
SELECT ..whatever.. FROM ..whatever.. WHERE ... \
... and [WORKORDER_SUB_ID] LIKE 'wid'   and [RESOURCE_ID] LIKE 'rid'   and ...  
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~    ~~~~~~~~~
    ^   build by setSubID               ^ build by setResourceID       ^ by other
```

you need to build this:

```
... and [WORKORDER_SUB_ID] LIKE 'wid'  \
and ( [RESOURCE_ID] LIKE 'rid1' or  [RESOURCE_ID] LIKE 'rid2' ) and ...
```

---

the quick fix (not recommended) is:

```
  m_operSet.setResourceID("COB' or [RESOURCE_ID] LIKE 'NIC' or [RESOURCE_ID] "
                          "LIKE 'SIC' or [RESOURCE_ID] LIKE 'PRS");
```

and

```
  m_strFilter += "and ( [RESOURCE_ID] LIKE '" + resID + "' ) ";
```

This way you end up with some kind of monster where apostrophes are added without consistency both on caller and on called function.

---

A better way:

```
void operationSet::setResourceID(std::vector<std::string> const &resIDs) {
  m_strFilter += "and (";
  for (auto it = resIDs.begin(); it != resIDs.end(); ++it) {
    if (it != resIDs.begin())
      m_strFilter += " or ";
    m_strFilter += " [RESOURCE_ID] LIKE '" + *it + "' ";
  }

  m_strFilter += " ) ";
}

m_operSet.setResourceID({"COB", "NIC", "SIC", "PRS"});
```

things you need to check if your application framework:

- `CString` and `std::string`. Most likely they didn't write an `operator +` for them. So you have 2 options: use `.c_str()` if they have an `operator +` for `CString` and `c strings`, or just use `std::vector<CString>`
- The code is written in `c++11`. See if your compiler supports `c++11`. If not you need to replace `auto` with `std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator`

and the call with:

```
std::string res_id_arr[4] = {"COB", "NIC", "SIC", "PRS"};
std::vector<std::string> res_ids(res_id_arr, res_id_arr + 4);
m_operSet.setResourceID(res_ids);
```

- Performance issues: A lot of copies will be passed around this way (but again that is true for `CString` also). So you really need to compile with `c++11` and use move semantics. There are resources on the net for moving in `c++11`